# Entity framework execution time

Tags: c#, .net, linq, frameworks, entity

I've noticed a massive difference in execution time with Entity Framework today. I would like to know why the first statement has so much overhead. For this query i'm retrieving 5500 trenddata values from the database (which shouldn't be a big deal).

This is the statement I used before:

```
TrendDataValues = new ObservableCollection<TrendDataValue>(_trendDataContext.TrendDatas.First(td => td.Id == argument.TrendDataId)
                                                                            .TrendDataValues
                                                                            .Where(tdv => tdv.ValueStartTimestamp >= argument.MinValue
                                                                                       && tdv.ValueStartTimestamp <= argument.MaxValue));
```

However, this statement takes over **10** seconds to run.

I've rewritten the first statement to the following one. This retrieves the exact same data. However, this statement returns values within **0.2** seconds.

```
 TrendDataValues = new ObservableCollection<TrendDataValue>(from td in _trendDataContext.TrendDatas.Where(d => d.Id == trendDataId)
                                                            from tdv in td.TrendDataValues
                                                            where tdv.ValueStartTimestamp >= argument.MinValue
                                                               && tdv.ValueEndTimestamp <= argument.MaxValue
                                                            select tdv);
```

Can somebody clarify the difference between the 2 statements?

Comment: In the first one you're comparing the start time to the min and max and in the second you are comparing the start time to the min and the end time to the max.  Is that just a typo?

Comment: Ah yes, that's a typo. However, in the current situation, it won't make a difference, since in this scenario the end and start timestamps are equal

Comment: Does your profiling tool suggest that the time is being spent executing the query on the SQL Server? If so, what is the difference between the two execution plans, if any.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: download http://www.linqpad.net/

Connect LINQ-pad to your database.

Run the two queries and take a look at the SQL tab to see if there is a difference in the SQL that is generated by the queries.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Chained method or query syntax if they are the same the resulting sql will be identical, it seems at first glance that in the second example you are implicitly creating a join, i.e. the two from / where statements will act similar to an inner join, whereas in the first you do not and are probably creating some form of cartesian product that the chained methods will have to search.

As the other dood suggests go use LinqPad and check out the sql generated, i bet it's not the same.

P.S. Effectively the 2nd example would actually take longer to compile! but if both examples were logically identical then method and query syntax would be the same execution speed.

Comment: Hi Paul, It sook me a while to figure out notepad (ran through the first examples) but after that it became clear. The first example only queries the trenddata-parent, and then loads all values in memory, and does the linq query over it's values in memory, while the 2nd one returns a scalar table with the trenddata values based on my query.

Comment: Yes Linqpad is simple but powerful. It is usually better to do the troubleshooting yourself in a case like this :)

Comment: Horses for courses... I use linqpad a lot as a RAD tool with all the benefits that RAD brings... if your more at home writing SQL then it may also be worth checking out Linqer, a simple SQL to Linq conversion tool

Answer (score 0):

As adviced in the answers above, I've tested both queries in linqpad.

The first one runs the following query:

```
SELECT TOP (1) [t0].[Id], [t0].[Tag], [t0].[Description], [t0].[PollingInterval], [t0].[Compression], [t0].[PlcLogDataTypeValue]
FROM [TrendDatas] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[Id] = @p0
```

The second one runs the following query:

```
SELECT [t1].[Id], [t1].[ValueStartTimestamp], [t1].[ValueEndTimestamp], [t1].[Value], [t1].[SerieNumber], [t1].[TrendData_Id]
FROM [TrendDatas] AS [t0], [TrendDataValues] AS [t1]
WHERE ([t1].[ValueStartTimestamp] >= @p0) AND ([t1].[ValueStartTimestamp] <= @p1) AND ([t0].[Id] = @p2) AND ([t1].[TrendData_Id] = [t0].[Id])
```

Apparently the first statement only returns the trenddata-parent object. I guessing how it's iterating over it's values (child elements), since I don't see a query or join referencing the TrendDataValues table, but i'm guessing this isn't going to be pretty.

The second query returns a better result which matches exactly what i'm asking.

Thanks for your support and +1 for the answers!